# Inserting time delay between processes in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming. I am trying to create a memory game which displays random numbers in a matrix in windows form at first. After some time I have to clear the cells and display options for answers on the left panel of screen. Could any one help me how to pause the matrix in form for a while before matrix blanks? I used text boxes to display matrix.

Also, Is there any standard code for matrix format display in C#?
Please help me..

Comment: -1 That's two completely unrelated questions. Create two separate questions.

Comment: There is no "standard code for matrix format display". I suppose you've used threads to get the matrix effect? In general, you should do exactly what you say you want to do - stop the matrix effect. Stop the threads. Post some code so we can have more info.

Comment: @MarkByers I'm pretty sure he already has the matrix-effect part covered.

Comment: OK: I removed the -1, but I still think it's a bad practice to ask two completely unrelated questions as part of a single question.

Answer (score 3):

In a Windows Forms project you should use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to create an event after a certain amount of time.

You should not use `Thread.Sleep` because this will make your GUI freeze.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clued up on C# myself but perhaps something like this is what you're looking for?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
this.Refresh();
```

Worth a try...

Comment: Not so good on a UI thread... makes it "unresponsive" to *many* interactions/events, including display refreshes!

Comment: @pst Ahh I see, well there I learned something as well. Thanks :-)